# How correctly draw a polygon with OpenTK

Tags: c#, opengl, graphics, drawing, opentk

I'm new to **OpenTK** and I'm using the following code to draw large number of polygons using **OpenTK**

```
public static void DrawPolygon(Point[] points)
{
    GL.Begin(BeginMode.Polygon); //IF I Change this to LineStrip every things will be OK
    int numberOfPoints = points.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++)
    {
        GL.Vertex2(points[i].X, points[i].Y);
    }
    GL.End();
}
```

And this is the configuration code which executes before calling the `DrawPolygon`

```
GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
GL.LoadIdentity();
GL.Ortho(0, width, 0, height, -1, 1); // Bottom-left corner pixel has coordinate (0, 0)
GL.Viewport(0, 0, (int)width, (int)height); 

GL.ClearColor(drawing.Color.Transparent);

GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
GL.LoadIdentity();
GL.Color3(pen.Color);
GL.PolygonMode(MaterialFace.FrontAndBack, PolygonMode.Line);
GL.PointSize(5f);
GL.LineWidth(2f);
```

Using this code when I save the rendered image to disk as png, the result will be like this

[image]

**result for:`GL.Begin(BeginMode.Polygon);`**

However If I change the first line of the `DrawPolygon` to `GL.Begin(BeginMode.LineStrip);` the polygon would be rendered as expected like this:

[image]

**result for : `GL.Begin(BeginMode.LineStrip);`**

Anyone knows why those two extra lines appears when using `BeginMode.Polygon`?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's because `GL_POLYGON`/`BeginMode.Polygon` only renders [convex polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polygon). I think that if you attempt render a concave polygon, as you're doing, the driver will try split up the geometry that you give it to render it as convex polygons, hence the unexpected lines in your example.

It's inadvisable to use the polygon rendering mode in OpenGL. The rendering of line strips and triangles is much more highly optimized, and therefore much, much quicker. I'd advise staying with line strips.

Comment: Is it possible to draw a polygon with `Triangle` mode? What if I want to draw filled polygons? In that case I cannot use `LineStrip` mode.

Comment: To draw your shape with triangles, you'll need to use a [polygon triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation) technique to decompose your polygon into a list of triangles.

Comment: If triangulation is quicker, can you provide a code sample?

Comment: I don't have a code sample to hand, but I can point you in the direction of something like [Triangle.NET](https://triangle.codeplex.com/), which uses Delaunay triangulation. I could also mention [OpenGL tesselation using the  GLU library](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_tessellation.html) (which I believe can be used through OpenTK), but I'm not sure how widely-used that is any more.